# Suddenly getting "ads by currency"

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, adware

Running Windows 7 and Chrome browser.

So I've suddenly been getting these ads (only noticed them today and I use the computer often enough to have noticed them before). I found a "Chrome Remote Desktop Host" program with an install date of yesterday. Now, I thought I already had this installed from a couple months ago, so I uninstalled it, but other than that the only recent install was Microsoft Visual C++ to get python's NumPy working two days ago.

I don't have any new Chrome extensions (I checked the list and it's all stuff I installed a long time ago and intentionally). Anyone else have these ads showing up? I'm guessing its adware on my system somewhere, because I run adblock and I'd think it would be good at catching this stuff (especially since it's appearing on every domain I go to), but I can't find any recent installs that would indicate adware.

EDIT: This is what my post looks like with these ads on it.

[image: screenshot of ads]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling chrome or closing suspicious programs from task manager to see if that helps make it go away? Do the ads appear in IE as well?

Comment: Old extensions being purchased by new authors and then filled with advertising/malware is a thing these days. Disable ALL Chrome extensions (regardless of age) and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: The irony of malware advertising anti-malware software...

Comment: @GrahamWager It did it on your post too, hahaha. http://i.imgur.com/dwgoFNP.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced the same thing today for the first time, and the culprit was a Chrome extension called [Chrome Notepad (v3.8.5)](http://www.crx4chrome.com/crx/8893/) which is no longer available. Once disabled, the ads were gone.

Comment: I have this too and will uninstall it immediately. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the [Chrome Currency Converter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-currency-converter/anbfhidldjknonaihbalghlebaijealk?hl=en-GB&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) installed. Removing this disabled these ads. I'm unsure if this is coincidence or not - as I installed an app yesterday. However, disabling the currency converter seems to have worked.